# Convert string comparison symbol to function in R

Tags: r

I would like to convert a comparison symbol in string format for example ">" to a comparison function in R. For example in backtick format `>`.

I know I could do:

```
compare <- function(symbol, left, right) {
  
  # possible symbols ">", ">=", "<", "<=", "="
  if(symbol == ">") return(`>`(left, right)) 
  if(symbol == ">=") return(`>=`(left, right)) 
  if(symbol == "<") return(`<`(left, right)) 
  if(symbol == "<=") return(`<=`(left, right)) 
  if(symbol == "=") return(`==`(left, right)) 

  return(NA)
}

compare(">", 2, 3) # returns FALSE
```

But as I said is there an option to convert to backtick or to implement this in an easy way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match.fun` which does exactly what you are trying to do :

```
compare <- function(symbol, left, right) {
  match.fun(symbol)(left, right)
}

compare(">", 2, 3)
#[1] FALSE

compare("<", 2, 3)
#[1] TRUE
```